# How to eneable --post302 curl option in php

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I'm trying to POST some atom+xml data to google calendar with its API. 
I've some problem because when putting the POST requst to google server I recive a 302 for the same url I requested plus a gsessionid parameter; No problem, I added the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option tu TRUE (like the cli -L option).
But actually the request is turned into a GET with this message:

```
Violate RFC 2616/10.3.3 and switch from POST to GET
```

Now, in linux curl cli I can set the --post302 parameter that instruct curl not to have this behaviour, and the POST is sent with no problem;

I didn't found any similar option in PHP....any idea of how to fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `curl_setopt($r_curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 2)`, as discussed here http://bugs.php.net/49571 . The constants CURL_REDIR_POST_301 / CURL_REDIR_POST_302 [mentioned here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) that may be used in the curl C API don't seem to be available in PHP.

Comment: Sry, I miswrote your code :) Obviously, it was CURLOPT_POSTREDIR